# Undefined ParentNode DOM error onmouseout

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

How's it,

[[here is a small page illustrating my problem](http://students.info.uaic.ro/~tudor.berechet/0sandbox/aperture/science/testing.xhtml)] (problem appears in Firefox)

So I have a function `onmouseout="regress(event, this)"` which tests if the mouse **actually** got outside the current element and any of it's children. ([more details on why I did this and what is the matter](http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3752159.htm)).
**If** the mouse is truly outside, I want to stop the animation on the button and reset a timer (which I did). And it works.

Only it doesn't. In Firefox (tested v5.0) that is. I get a DOM related error. `parentNode` of the element that triggered the function is "" and then the parent of that will be "undefined" and then I get an error and the code explodes.

Here's the baffling part: This error occurs only when the mouse truly goes off the button area. There's another case when the onmouseout event gets triggered (for the avoidance of which I'm using this function). Which is onmouseout off a child of the button to another child of the button. In this case, the `parentNode` works fine, going from buttonChild to button to buttonParent to blabla to BODY and then stops.

My question is, why does the undefined error appear in one case and doesn't in the other. Mind you that there are no errors in Chrome or IE9. Also how can I fix it?

This baffles me. Thank you for any help.

I am baffled.

Also here is the javascript function:

```
function regress(evt, x){
    //if (!e && window.event) 
    if (window.event) 
        var e = window.event;
    else
        var e = evt; //if we got here, you're using Firefox
    var reltg = (e.relatedTarget) ? e.relatedTarget : e.toElement;

    while (reltg.tagName != 'body')
    {   
        //alert(reltg.id+" == " + x.id);
        if (reltg.id == x.id)
        {

            return;
        }
        reltg = reltg.parentNode;
        //alert(reltg.tagName);
    }
    // I'm on true mouseout, do stuff here:
    $("#"+x.id+"ThickParent").stop(true, false);
    $("#"+x.id+"ThickParent").width(0);

    canStartAgain=true;

    stopInterval = true;
    timerValue = 1.50;
    $("#"+x.id+"Timer").html("");
    //thanks to: http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3752159.htm
}
```

Uncomment `//alert(reltg.id+" == " + x.id);` to see exactly when `onmouseout` got triggered and what element `reltg.parentNode` is on at what time.

Comment: I get an error on this line in FF5: `while (reltg.tagName != 'body')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this same problem a few months ago. You will notice that exiting by the top side the error don't happen. By some reason the "body" tag is narrowed to fit the the inner div and extended to the top and when moving to botton(or leff, or right) FF triggers the event with a related target pointing to the "html" tag and in your loop the stop condition is the tag being the "body" one. The parent of the "html" tag is the document and the document's parent is `null` and the error is throw when you try to access the `tagName` property of `null`. To achieve the expected result you must change your stop condition to `while (reltg.tagName != 'html')` or even a most error resilient as `while (reltg && (reltg.tagName != 'body'))`.

Comment: Why thank you Prusse. Now I know what happens. But why on earth did Mozilla do that? It doesn't make any sense...

Comment: That is why I used "some reason" =)... Maybe it should read "no rhyme or reason", sorry English is not my first language.